# Excel VBA. Run-time error 1004 on jumping to next Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I keep getting Run-time error 1004 (Application-defined or object-defined error) on the stage

```
Next ws1
```

It is clear that I can't jump on the next worksheet, but it is obscure for me how to fix this issue.
The code itself:

```
Sub Compare_Status()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsComp As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim idCol1 As Long, idCol2 As Long
    Dim statusCol1 As Long, statusCol2 As Long
    Dim fileA1 As String
    
    fileA1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Range("A1").Value
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileA1)
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook    
    Set wsComp = wb2.Sheets("Compare") 
    
    wsComp.Cells.ClearContents
    wsComp.Cells(1, 1).Value = fileA1     
    compRow = 4
        
    For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets
        idCol2 = 0
        statusCol2 = 0
        For j = 1 To ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If ws2.Cells(1, j).Value = "ID marker" Then
                idCol2 = j
            ElseIf ws2.Cells(1, j).Value = "ID of result" Then
                idCol2 = j
            ElseIf ws2.Cells(1, j).Value = "Status" Then
                statusCol2 = j
            End If
            If idCol2 > 0 And statusCol2 > 0 Then Exit For
        Next j

        For Each ws1 In wb1.Worksheets
            idCol1 = 0
            statusCol1 = 0
            For j = 1 To ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                If ws1.Cells(1, j).Value = "ID marker" Then
                    idCol1 = j
                ElseIf ws1.Cells(1, j).Value = "ID of result" Then
                    idCol1 = j
                ElseIf ws1.Cells(1, j).Value = "Status" Then
                    statusCol1 = j
                End If
                If idCol1 > 0 And statusCol1 > 0 Then Exit For
            Next j
            
            If (idCol1 > 0 And statusCol1 > 0) Then
                For i = 2 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
                    Dim foundId As Range
                    If (ws2.Cells(i, idCol2).Value = "No") Then
                        Set foundId = ws1.Columns(idCol1).Find(ws2.Cells(i, idCol2).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                        If Not foundId Is Nothing Then
                            If ws2.Cells(i, statusCol2).Value = "No" And ws1.Cells(foundId.Row, statusCol1).Value = "Yes" Then
                                    ws1.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=wsComp.Rows(compRow)
                                    compRow = compRow + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                     End If
                Next i
                compRow = compRow + 2
            End If
        Next ws1
    Next ws2
    
    wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

I tried looking into Locals window, but I don't quite understand what to look for to fix the error

Comment: @braX Sorry for mess with End Ifs, it's alright in the code itself. just the problem of copy-pasting. So it's def not a cause

Comment: So, you get a runtime error when trying to execute the Next ws1 line? Weird.

Comment: @jkpieterse Yep, tested using Stop

Comment: @Notus_Panda  Nah, in the code I use Next ws1. Just a small mistake in the post, I ll edit it :)

Comment: You can check `ws1.Name` for instance.

Comment: @Blackcat the name matches the name of the file I need to open, everything seems to be fine

Comment: `If (ws2.Cells(i, idCol2).Value = “No”) Then` looks like you have "smart quotes" there?

Comment: @TimWilliams another copy-paste issue, the error is not the result of syntax

Comment: Is there a "Debug" button in the error pop-up?

Comment: `Set foundId = ws1.Columns(idCol1).Find(ws2.Cells(i, idCol2).Value, ...` are you actually searching for the value "No" here?

Comment: @TimWilliams No Debug button((( As for the value "No", I should mention how this macro was intended to work. It needs to compare names of Worksheets in active Workbook and Workbook path for which is in range "A1", then on Worksheets with same names, it examines if there is Column with name "Status" on the Worksheet. If yes, it compares the values in column with Status in both rows with same value in column ID (like Vlookup) in both files. If in first file the value of Status is "No" and in second file is "Yes" for the row with same ID, then copy it to the list "Compare"

Comment: OK I'm not seeing where you match on id though?  You only ever look for "No" to locate `foundId`.   On the error - take a look at your error setting in the VBA editor (tools >> options >> general).  "Break in class module" is a good selection there.

Comment: Also: `For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets` will include the "Compare" worksheet, which has no headers, so you'll go into the `For Each ws1 In wb1.Worksheets` loop with `idCol2` and `statusCol2` both = 0